# Can't update the state on this React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the `select` tag to update the selected value with the `state.value` prop according to this [React document](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag).

The parent Component is passing `title` as `props` to this Component, the problem is that I'm getting this error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

And I don't understand why is looping recursively. Would you please help me with this?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class BookShelfChanger extends Component {
    state = {
        value: '',
        isMounted: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isMounted: true })
    }

    checkOptions(title) {
        if(!this.state.isMounted) return

        let val;

        switch(title) {
            case 'currentlyReading':
                this.setState({ value: title})
                val = 'Currently Reading'
                break

            case 'wantToRead':
                this.setState({ value: title})
                val = 'Want To Read' 
                break

            case 'read':
                this.setState({ value: title})
                val = 'Read'
                break
            default:
        }
        return val
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.checkOptions}>
                    <option value="move" disabled>Move to...</option>
                    <option value="currentlyReading">{this.checkOptions(this.props.title)}</option>
                    <option value="wantToRead">{this.checkOptions(this.props.title)}</option>
                    <option value="read">{this.checkOptions(this.props.title)}</option>
                    <option value="none">None</option>
                </select>
        )
    }
}

export default BookShelfChanger
```

Comment: You are calling `this.checkOptions(this.props.title)` directly in your render method, which results in a `setState`, which results in a re-render, and the infinite loop continues.

Comment: Makes totally sense. Now, how could update the options' content based on the `title` prop without including it on the tag's body?

Comment: You could just write `<option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should not call setState inside your render function. This would lead to infinite loop of calling setState. Whenever you setState, React re-renders, if you call setState inside render, then it would lead another render which would again lead to setState and loop continues. Thats why you are seeing the error. Instead  you can try following:

```
 checkOptions=(event, )=>{

    let val;
    console.log(event.target.value) // Gives you the selected option's value

}

render() {
    return (
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.checkOptions}>
                <option value="move" disabled>Move to...</option>
                <option value="currentlyReading">currentlyReading</option>
                <option value="wantToRead">wantToRead</option>
                <option value="read">read</option>
                <option value="none">None</option>
            </select>
    )
}
```

Comment: That worked perfect. But now every time that I click on an option, `state.value` holds the previous value and not the one that I'm clicking. Do you know why it behaves that way?

Comment: Yes, the setState is Asynchronous function, hence if you try to check the set value immediately, it might not have changed, hence I would use something like this:   
        this.setState({value : event.target.value}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.value)
        })

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the onChange to your component or else this.checkOptions runs whenever the component is rendered. checkOptions causes the component to update which leads to the infinite loop.

Try this:

```
<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.checkOptions.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Even with checkOptions converted to an arrow function.